# when i scroll button position is changing in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I have implemented a `ListView`. From `ListView` I am adding a products to cart. My problem is if i add a first product i am changing a button name `Addtocart` to `Added` if i scroll `ListView` 4th position product button name is changing to Added.

How can I resolve this ?

Here my code:

```
holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setTag(position);
holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {        
            holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setText("Added");
    }
});
```

Adapter Class:

class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
    public Context context;


    public ListAdapter(Context a,List<BusinessCatalogVariables> listDataHeader) {
        this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        context = a;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return catalogList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        final ViewHolderGrid holderForGrid;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.catalog_list_item, null);
            holderForGrid = new ViewHolderGrid(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holderForGrid);

        } else {
            holderForGrid = (ViewHolderGrid) convertView.getTag();
        }

        finalCatalogVariables Catalog = catalogList.get(position);

        holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setClickable(false);


        holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setTag(position);

        holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                 int position1=(Integer)arg0.getTag();

                AddedProduct = (String) holderForGrid.CatalogHeader.getText();
                holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setText("Added");


            }
        });



        return convertView;
    }



    private class ViewHolderGrid {

        Button AddtoCart = null;

        ViewHolderGrid(View convertView) {


            AddtoCart = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_AddtoCart);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can u pls post your adapter class?

Comment: create Product getter setter class. then keep isAdded boolean variable. then in getView check isAdded variable and change the button Add cart to Added... this is perfect way to handle listview item.

Comment: Please check my adapter class

Comment: @AmolSawant96Kuli ++1 for your answer it is working good!!! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Simon and switch to recycler view soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create `boolean` variable `added` in `finalCatalogVariables` class.
and create getter,setter method for this variable.
like,

```
class finalCatalogVariables{

    // other variable and methods

    boolean added;

    public boolean isAdded()
    {
       return this.added;
    }

    public void setAdded(boolean added){
       this.added = added;
    }
}
```

then in `getView` method on click of `holderForGrid.AddtoCart`

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        final ViewHolderGrid holderForGrid;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.catalog_list_item, null);
            holderForGrid = new ViewHolderGrid(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holderForGrid);

        } else {
            holderForGrid = (ViewHolderGrid) convertView.getTag();
        }

        finalCatalogVariables catalog = catalogList.get(position);

        if(catalog.isAdded()){
             holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setText("Added");
        }else{
              holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setText("Add to cart");
        }

        holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setClickable(false);


        holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setTag(position);

        holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                catalog.setAdded(true);    

                 int position1=(Integer)arg0.getTag();

                AddedProduct = (String) holderForGrid.CatalogHeader.getText();
               // holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setText("Added");


            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: pleasure is all mine,  next time switch to RecycleView if you want to show list or Grid in android. for example you can visit.  http://amolsawant88.blogspot.in/2015/08/easy-way-to-highlight-selected-rowitem.html

Comment: Can u suggest me how to save a added products into session. in above code if i add multiple products to cart how to store added values to session

Comment: Oh sry i clicked somewhere

Comment: i think you need local db for that to store it.

Comment: Ok i will try that. i thought to store in session

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = Session.getInstance().getImageLoader();
 //write your declaration code 


    List m = Yourarray.get(position);

    // thumbnail image


  convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //your code
         int position1=(Integer)arg0.getTag();

            AddedProduct = (String) holderForGrid.CatalogHeader.getText();
            holderForGrid.AddtoCart.setText("Added");

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Please check my adapter class

Answer (score 0):

Override below mentioned two methods in your adapter class.

```
Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {

return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

return position;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that if you change the button on a view and then scroll far enough for the view to disappear, Android will assign the view position to another item in the listView.

You need to maintain somehow the status "added" or not of each product and let your adapter decide what label to display based on that.